# AWS - Bastion ssh tunnel to access RDS -- connecting to SSH server but not MySQL server

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, ssh-tunnel, navicat

I have a Bastion host set up to be able to SSH into my RDS instance. I'm using Navicat 12 to make the connection to the database, and I'm reaching the SSH server on both Navicat as well as PuTTY, but I'm not able to actually reach the RDS instance and I'm getting the following error:

> 2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial
>   communication packet', system error: 0 "Internal error/check (Not
>   system error)"

Here are the settings I'm using to connect:

```
SSH settings:
Host: my bastion public DNS
Port: 22
Username: ec2-user
Authentication Method: public key
Private key: my key path
Passphrase: none

Connection Settings:
Endpoint: my rds endpoint
Port: 3306
Username: my rds username
Password: my rds password
(I've also tried root with no password on this to test)

Security Group Info:
Bastion-
SSH/TCP/22/my local IP

RDS-
MYSQL/Aurora / TCP/3306/anywhere
```

If anyone can offer any sort of guidance or troubleshooting, I would super appreciate it!

Comment: Is the security group of the RDS server configured to allow connections from the EC2 bastion server?

Comment: I have 4 rules for inbound on my RDS security group.                                          
All MYSQL/Aurora - TCP - 3306 and the sources as follows: anywhere, my scripts instance, my webserver, and my bastion

Answer (score 0):

AWS do not allow direct SSH access onto their RDS instances, I couldn't find where they state it in there documentation but there is this Forum where they say:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=93277

However - If you need to run scripts directly against the RDS you can install psql (or equivalent) on the bastion and connect to it through that.

Comment: I have a linux bastion ec2 instance set up, and I can SSH into the bastion, but not into the RDS instance from the bastion if that makes sense.

Comment: It makes sense, but SSH access to AWS RDS instances is not allowed, amazon do not allow it, no matter what location you come in from, security group or any other factor. They do this as it should never be needed, any updates you want to do can be done through the console. You can connect to it through any DB editor with the username and password you set on creation, but that wont be SSH access.

Comment: From what I'm understanding from our provider, SSH tunneling through a bastion is the only way to access an RDS instance that is marked as not publicly accessible, and there's a ton of information on how to do this online, so I'm confused as to where you're getting that AWS doesn't allow this? The thread that you shared is from 2012, so it's likely they've updated that since then.

Comment: Anyone have an answer to this? I am sure it is allowed now.